# SFML: How to overload Packet operator >> with a std::vector?

Tags: vector, udp, sfml, packet

I'm currently programming a UDP based game and I need to inform to every new player that connects to the game about every connected player's position and other data. If I could overload the << and >> operators to send a packet with all the player's data stored on the server.
How I could solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is something like that what you mean?

```
template<typename T>
sf::Packet& operator<<(sf::Packet& packet, std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    return packet << vec.at(0) << vec.at(1)  << vec.at(2);
}

template<typename T>
sf::Packet& operator>>(sf::Packet& packet, std::vector<T>& vec)
{
    return packet >> vec.at(0)  >> vec.at(1)  >> vec.at(2);
}
```

Comment: Yeah it was that! Ty :)